# Textbox Outside DetailsView - RequiredFieldValidator Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, requiredfieldvalidator

all.  This is officially my first post of StackOverflow.  Great site, and has helped me often, but I cannot find the answer to this.

I have an asp.net form with a TextBox that has a RequiredFieldValidator. Following this is a DetailsView with Edit and Delete enabled. The Textbox is NOT inside the DetailsView.  I need the RequiredFieldValidator to fire when I click the Edit and/or Delete commands.

Here is my code for the two controls.  I can post it all with code behind but it is a lot to post if not needed.

TIA for your assistance.

Ali
........................................................................

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReason" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvReason" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="txtReason" 
        ErrorMessage="Reason is required for Edit/Delete"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:DetailsView ID="dvCOHDetail" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="700px" DataKeyNames="RecID" DataSourceID="sdsCOHIncident" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnDatabound="dvCOHDetail_DataBound" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" OnItemUpdated="dvCOHDetail_ItemUpdated"  OnItemDeleting="dvCOHDetail_ItemDeleting">
   <Fields>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION:">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat=server Text="Edit" CommandName="edit"/>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm ( 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?' )"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

........................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group all the controls that you want to **validate** and that **occurs validation**. As you want to validate the **TextBox** on **LinkButton** click you have to set the **ValidationGroup** property of the **TextBox** that you want to validate and the **LinkButtons** that occurs the validation with a same value(any **string**).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReason" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:DetailsView ID="dvCOHDetail" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="700px" DataKeyNames="RecID" DataSourceID="sdsCOHIncident" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnDatabound="dvCOHDetail_DataBound" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" OnItemUpdated="dvCOHDetail_ItemUpdated"  OnItemDeleting="dvCOHDetail_ItemDeleting">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION:">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit"/>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm ( 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?' )"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField> 
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvReason" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="txtReason"
    ErrorMessage="Reason is required for Edit/Delete" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" EnableClientScript="False"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Perfect; I understand now!  In case you can't tell, I'm a bit of a .net newbie.  Thank you both for your answers!

Comment: You are welcome.You might check the following url to know more about ValidationGroup.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I believe that if you set the ValidationGroup attribute of both of the buttons within the DetailsView as well as on the RequiredFieldValidator, when the buttons are clicked the validator should fire its validate event.  The ValidationGroup attribute can be any string you want to describe the group of validations that you are attempting to validate.